# Add Asp Role SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, forms-authentication, role-provider

Has anyone been able to successfully run the command as below

```
New-SPSite https://sitename/sites/newsite -owner (New-SPClaimsPrincipal "Sales Manager Role" -IdentityProvider "myRoleProvider")
```

This is from the Microsoft docs below

[Example 5](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/new-spclaimsprincipal?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: If you're having a problem it would help to explain what you're tying to set up and what happened when you ran the command. Because the answer to the question as it stands now is, "yes".

Comment: I am trying to add an ASPNet Membership Role via PowerShell